# Get current state of ui-router with ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two buttons. I want to use ng-if to make sure that one of the buttons is visible only when you are at a certain page in the application.

I want to other button to be visible everywhere in the application EXCEPT when you are at that certain page.

So I thought that I could use ng-if.

BUTTON 1

```
<md-button ng-if="$state.current.path === example" class="md-icon-  button" aria-label="More" ui-sref="health">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/back.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
```

BUTTON 2

```
        <md-button ng-if="!($state.current.path === example)"class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More" ng-click="toggleHamburger()">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/menu.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
```

In my controller i'm using the regular ui-router syntax (like below)

```
.state('example', {
        url: "/example",
        templateUrl: "components/examples/example.html"
    })
```

However this does not work: How can I access the current state of the UI router and use it to evaluate whether my button should be visible or not?

Comment: What error message are you receiving in the console?

Comment: What and where doesn't work?

Comment: none, the buttons are both visible. I don't think i'm succeeding in getting the current route at all. I'm not sure about the syntax

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to expose the state in your scope.

Controller:

```
// ... stuff
$scope.currentPath = $state.current.path
// ... more stuff
```

View:

```
<md-button ng-if="currentPath === 'example'" class="md-icon-  button" aria-label="More" ui-sref="health">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/back.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Comment: if this is correct then it could just be $state.current.path instead of $state.currentPath in the ng-if

Comment: Does `$state` automatically expose itself in the scope? If it does then sure, but if it doesn't, you could name it an access it however you choose when you do

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$location.path()` here like this.

```
ng-if="$location.path() === example"
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler is to use ui-sref-active directive, add a class that show the element and that it

## Example

```
<ui-sref-active="show-element" class="md-icon-button ng-hide"
```

And then in your css:

```
.show-element {
  display: block/inline-block;
}
```

Comment: How would I do that?